# JQuery exclude certain div inputs from form serializing

Tags: jquery

Upon submission of a form, I am serializing my data so I can catch the fields and add records to my database.  I understand that any fields with a 'name' property will be serialized by jQuery.

In the div called 'rrule_section', I do NOT want any of those inputs to be serialized at all!  I need to keep their 'name' properties so other certain javascripts work, so I cannot simply leave the 'name' blank to solve this problem.

I will have a bunch of different input types in rrule_section, but here is a sample of my form below.

```
<div id="formEventModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">

<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header"></div>
        <div class="modal-body">

    <form id="appointmentForm" class="form-horizontal">

       <input disabled type="text" id="attending_name" name="attending_name" class="form-control" value="">

       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="waiting_list_start" name="waiting_list_start" />

    <div name="rrule-gen" id="rrule_section">
       <input type="radio" name="event-recurring" value="no" checked="checked"> No
       <input type="radio" name="event-recurring" value="yes"> Yes
       <select name="freq">
            <option value="daily" class="days">Daily</option>
            <option value="weekly" class="weeks">Weekly</option>
            <option value="monthly" class="months">Monthly</option>
            <option value="yearly" class="years">Yearly</option>
       </select>
       <input type="text" name="until" id="end-date" disabled="disabled" class="hasDatepicker dont_serialize">
    </div>

</form>

...
...
```

Upon form submission, I have this:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_insert.php?table=appointments",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#formEventModal #appointmentForm').serialize(),
 ....
```

I was thinking I need to use the .not selector, but it still serializes everything:

```
$('#formEventModal #appointmentForm').not('#rrule_section').serialize()
```

How can I stop rrule_section inputs from being serialized?

Comment: There is no point in wanting to serialize `#formEventModal` as it is not part of the form.

Comment: Why would you want to use `serialize` if you are posting `json`?  Use [`json.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to tcj for putting me on the right track, I ended up just added a class to each input that I don't want serialized.  Then I use this:

```
data: $('#appointmentForm').find(':input').not('.dont_serialize').serialize(),
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When selecting multiple elements in jQuery, you have to put a comma after each element so `data: $('#formEventModal, #appointmentForm').serialize()`, but in your case it won't help, instead, you can add your fields manually like this :

`data: $('#attending_name, #waiting_list_start').serialize(),`

or another alternative like so :

`data: 'attending_name=' + $('#attending_name').val() + '&waiting_list_start=' + $('#waiting_list_start').val();`

Or use this method to automatically gather all fields outside `#rrule_section` :

`data: $('#appointmentForm > :not([id="rrule_section"])').serialize();`

or also this one is its equivalent to follow the way you wrote it (you were almost right, just forgot to select the children) :

`data: $('#appointmentForm').children().not('#rrule_section').serialize();`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I suppose this would work, however this was a sample of my form. There are many many inputs that are being serialized properly.  I'd have to then list all of them. I was hoping for a way to omit the ones I dont need which are in div rrule_section

Comment: Just updated my code with the last method you want to use.

Comment: @chris.cavage : look at the second solution I provided, it is working as you intend it to, I don't get why I got downvoted tho.

Comment: I'll check it out when I'm back at it. I agree, I have no idea why I even got down voted. I provided useful insight, code, a clear question. It should be necessary for the person who down votes to explain why. I'll get right back to you.

Comment: I find that your two ideas omit serializing other parts of my form if they are in other divs.